# Avoiding $GLOBAL state in PHP with dependancy injection?

Tags: php, design-patterns, reflection, dependency-injection, global-variables

I have encountered a situation where I would like to avoid using `$GLOBAL` state, but cannot workout how to do so. I believe Reflection and Dependancy injection could solve this:

Here is a contrived example (Yes I know its a little bent...); Say we have a `Calculator` class and helper functions that basically replicate its functionality e.g. `add, subtract`. Now we also want a `history` of our calculations to be accessible.

How can I use these helper functions without having to manually insert the `Calculator` as a dependancy?

```
class Calculator
{
    private $history = [];

    public function add(int $a, int $b): int
    {
        $result = $a + $b;

        $this->history[] = $result;

        return $result;
    }

    public function subtract(int $a, int $b): int
    {
        $result = $a - $b;

        $this->history[] = $result;

        return $result;
    }

    public function history(): array
    {
        return $this->history;
    }
}

function add(int $a, int $b): int
{
    $calculator = new Calculator;
    return $calculator->add($a, $b);
}

function subtract(int $a, int $b): int
{
    $calculator = new Calculator;
    return $calculator->subtract($a, $b);
}

function history(): array
{
    $calculator = new Calculator;
    return $calculator->history(); // Clearly this will be empty
}
```

See what I mean? Currently calling `history()` will of course return an empty array...

Of course this would work:

```
function add(Calculator $calculator, int $a, int $b): int
{
    return $calculator->add($a, $b);
}

function history(Calculator $calculator): array
{
    return $calculator->history();
}
```

Although if i use this as a package its very error prone, labour intensive to manually wire up these dependancies... let alone every time I call a helper function.

Another method that would work is globals:

```
$GLOBALS['calculator'] = new Calculator;

function add(int $a, int $b): int
{
    return $GLOBALS['calculator']->add($a, $b);
}

function history(): array
{
    return $GLOBALS['calculator']->history();
}
```

Although ... yuk yuk yuk. No thank you.

HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually when people turn to an IoC, aka DI Container.

You could also use the singleton pattern, providing a static accessor for a single instance of your class.  You can track history, or state, in the calculator class because there will only be one instance of this class.

```
class Calculator
{
    private static $instance;

    public static getInstance(): Calculator
    {
        if (static::$instance === null) {
           static::$instance = new Calculator;
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    ...rest of code...
}

Calculator::getInstance()->add($x, $y);
```

The main concern with statics is state and testability, your use of $GLOBALS for global functions doesn't seem too problematic to me as you're essentially using $GLOBALS as a container or service locator.

Comment: Late static binding! I should have thought of this. Okay this is perfect for my use-case.